# Rate of change, square area by time

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question describes a square with sides defined by $s = 2+t²$, where $t = time$. It asks to define the variation rate of the area when $t = 2$

My result:

$ t = time $,
$ s = side $,
$ A = area $

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dA}{ds}.\frac{ds}{dt}$$

Area derivative: $$\frac{dA}{ds} = 2s$$
Side derivative: $$\frac{ds}{dt} = 2t$$

When $t = 2$:

$$\frac{dA}{dt}|_{t=2} = 2(2+2)².2(2)$$
$$\frac{dA}{dt}|_{t=2} = 32$$

But the answer says:  48.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A'(2) = 4st = 4(2 + t^2)t|_{t=2} = 48$